# wrong number of arguements to if

Tags: excel, parsing, if-statement

Working on a payroll integration sheet for a tiered payroll structure. I have rearranged to allow for IF and THEN structure, tried as IF condition for validation only. Bending my eyes around this and hoping someone can prodigy this quickly without losing my mind today. I know im overlooking it, whos got fast eyes here. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLO86.jpg)

original:

=IF(AND(C26<23.9),(C26=24-31.9),(C26=32-39.9),(THEN(B26*11,B26*12,B26*13,B26*14)))

Comment: There’s no THEN in the IF formula.  Suggest you check the documentation.

Comment: A single IF cannot determine 4 separate returns, Perhaps you are thinking of the newer IFS function. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45

Comment: also `C26=32-39.9` is asking if `C26 = -7.9` not 32 through 39.9

Answer (score 3):

TBH, this is a bit of a cystal ball prediction but it seems you are looking to return different values based on C26 being within one of three ranges or another if outside all 3.

The literal translation would be,

```
=if(C26<24, B26*11, if(and(C26>=24, C26<32), B26*12, if(and(C26>=32, C26<40), B26*13, B26*14)))
```

However, this can be tightened up by reversing the flow of logic and only returning B26's modifier..

```
=B26*if(C26>=40, 14, if(C26>=32, 13, if(C26>=24, 12, 11)))
```

Further formula adjustment might produce,

```
=B26*lookup(C26, {0, 24, 32, 40}, {11, 12, 13, 14})
```

The newer IFS function would look like,

```
=B26*ifs(C26>=40, 14, C26>=32, 13, C26>=24, 12, TRUE, 11)
```

One final attempt using booleans for addition,

```
=B26*(11+(C26>=24)+(C26>=32)+(C26>=40))
```

Comment: How does =B26*lookup(C26, {0, 24, 32, 40}, {11, 12, 13, 14}) work please?

Comment: It returns the value from the second array (`{11, 12, 13, 14}`) at the position where it found an approximate match to C26 in the first array (`{0, 24, 32, 40}`) . Like using vlookup with true on sorted data.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
=(MATCH(C26,{-1E+99,24,32,40})+10)*B26
```

Or if you have OFFICE 365 Excel:

```
=IFERROR(IFS(C26>=40,14,C26>=32,13,C26>=24,12),11)*B26
```